# When does the javascript function need empty parenthesis after require statement?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using module.exports for exporting functions. Most of them are imported like this:

```
const logger = require('../middleware/logger')
```

I understand that if I needed to pass an argument to the function I would use:

```
const logger = require('../middleware/logger')(arg)
```

But recently I ran into a function I need to call with empy parenthesis:

```
require('./startup/db')()
```

Otherwise The connection to database is not established. There is code from './startup/db' :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true)
const logger = require('../middleware/logger')

module.exports = function () {
   mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/data', {
         useNewUrlParser: true,
         useUnifiedTopology: true,
      })
      .then(() => logger.info('Connected to MongoDB'))
}
```

Could anyone explain when `require('module')` is not working and I should use `require('module')()` instead?

Comment: When a function returns a function and you want to call it immediately without saving the returned function reference in some variable, you can do `foo()()` which means that call a function that is returned by calling `foo` function.

Answer (score 3):

This is because `'./startup/db'` returns a function instead of a value. This function needs to be called else just a reference to the function is stored. 
Now since this function does not require a parameter and just needs to be invoked, no values are passed to it.